# Squid Not Blocking HTTPS

Tags: squid

I broke my squid proxy. It stopped blocking HTTPS sites in the acl.denied_domains file, but still blocks the HTTP sites.

This was working till I edited my squid.conf file, and I do not have a backup.

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
visible_hostname omiw2321.orthman.local
cache_mgr support@orthman.com
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1


# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing # should be allowed # DEFAULT BLOCKING
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 80      # WWW
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 90      # eproduction
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535        # unregistered ports
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost http_access allow manager localhost http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports
# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent # web applications running on the proxy server who think the only # one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS #

# DENIED DOMAINS
acl denied_domains dstdomain "acl.denied_domains"
http_access deny denied_domains
# KEYWORD BLOCKING
acl keywords url_regex "acl.keywords"
http_access deny keywords
# Twitter
acl twitter src "acl.twitter.ips"
acl twitter.dst dstdomain "twitter.hosts"
http_access allow twitter twitter.dst

# FACEBOOK
acl facebook src "acl.facebook.ips"
acl facebook.dst dstdomain "facebook.hosts"
http_access allow facebook facebook.dst

# YOUTUBE
acl youtube src  "acl.youtube.ips"
acl youtube.dst dstdomain "youtube.hosts"
http_access allow youtube youtube.dst

# EBAY
acl ebay src "acl.ebay.ips"
acl ebay.dst dstdomain "ebay.hosts"
http_access allow ebay ebay.dst


# LinkedIN
acl linkedin src "acl.linkedin.ips"
acl linkedin.dst dstdomain "linkedin.hosts"
http_access allow linkedin linkedin.dst

# Pandora
acl pandora src "acl.pandora.ips"
acl pandora.dst dstdomain "pandora.hosts"
http_access allow pandora pandora.dst

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks # from where browsing should be allowed http_access allow localnet http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

Comment: Do you have examples of domains listed in the denied domain file?

Answer (score -1):

Deny all other access to this proxy: put `http_access deny all` at the end.

Comment: How does this help?